# Hotkey to select content of the current cell

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, vba, hotkeys

is there a hot-key or a sequence of hot-keys to select the content of a table-cell in MS-word? the cursor is within that cell.

All I found is Tab for next cells content and Shift+Tab for previous cells content.

Different hot key pages on the web show "toolbar 32778" as hot-key.

I need this information for a VBA Macro.

Comment: What happens if you `Tab` then `Shift-Tab` immediately?

Comment: it worked while recording a macro, but failed when I put it into another macro, returning run-time error 5678.
Macro text: 
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="bmF2"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

Comment: In that code, you move right then left *by cell*, isn't your selection at that moment the entire cell contents (check)? You are deleting a *character* afterwards...

Comment: I posted the code the macro recorded. during recording did it delete the whole content with one click. one solution of the problem is tab then Shift-Tab, but measures have to be prepared to not jump out of the cell.  (in fact, the delete is not related to my question). Now I have written a completely different approach where I marked the whole content of the cell as a bookmark and changing the text will update the bookmark as well, but that's another story.